# Why is pandas adding new columns to my new excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two excel files with the same column names together, but there seems to be a problem as there are new empty columns/spaces being added to my new excel file, and i don't know why.

I used `pd.concat()` function which was supposed to concat the two files into one single sheet and make a new file, but when it adds the table in the second file to the first file, new columns/spaces are added to the new merged file.

```py
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
dfs =  pd.DataFrame()

dfs = [pd.read_excel(p,) for p in file_list]
print(dfs[0].shape)
res = pd.concat(dfs)
```

That is a snippet of my code

I also added a picture of what the result i am getting now looks like
[image: This is what i am getting for the new file now which is wrong]

Comment: Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat respects the column names, so is not like a plain vector concatenate, try to check if the column names are the same among all your source files. If no, you can normalize them, rename them or move to a vector base format like numpy arrays.